# C# WPF how to change x:FieldModifier in Code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a abstract Usercontrol that includes a Shape and a Textbox. So if I create a Class that Inheritance to my Usercontrol, I can say that that Shape is a Rectangle and in the textbox I can say that it Contains a text like "rectangle". I gived every shape & textbox a Name, but I cant reach them by name. So I need to make those Public which is as far as I know is only  possible with the x:Fieldmofifier which I only can use in the XAML editor. So is there any way to make those Shape & Textbox public? (Sorry for my bad english)

```
abstract public partial class Tool : UserControl
{
    public Tool(int marginRight, Shape shape,string text, string name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext += null;
        grid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0) { Right = marginRight };
        Width = 60;
        Height = 60;
        shape.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        shape.StrokeThickness = 0.50;
        shape.Fill = Brushes.White;
        shape.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        shape.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        grid.Children.Add(shape);
        shape.Name = "sp_shape";

        TextBox textblock = new TextBox()
        {
            IsReadOnly = true,
            Text = text,
            FontSize = 10,
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            Foreground = Brushes.Black,
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
            TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Background = Brushes.Transparent,
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
            Name = "tb_shape",
            IsEnabled = true,

        };

        grid.Children.Add(textblock);
```

...

```
public class CircleTool : Tool
{
    public CircleTool() : base(0, new Ellipse()
    {
        Width = 35,
        Height = 35,
    }, "Kreis", "_circle")
    {
        //nothing / empty
    }
```

...

```
                    Tool el = (Tool)element;
                    var b = el.grid. <-- i wanna talk to my childs here
```

I can only talk to my grid, because its created in xaml in wpf . So I can change the FieldModifier to public, but not my Shapes & Textbox.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UML_Softwaremodellierung.Tool"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
         compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UML_Softwaremodellierung"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="60" d:DesignWidth="60"
         AllowDrop="true"
         >
<Grid x:Name="grid" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Creating UI elements in code behind is bad practice. What you are doing here could easily be done with DataTemplates. Or with ControlTemplates of custom controls. Please read the [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview) article on MS Docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are creating it in code behind, however simply make the TextBox a public member of the Tool class, e.g. a public readonly property:

```
public partial abstract class Tool : UserControl
{
    public TextBox TextBox { get; }

    public Tool(...)
    {
        ...
        TextBox = new TextBox
        {
           ...
        };

        grid.Children.Add(TextBox);
    }
}
```

Then access it like this:

```
var tb = el.TextBox;
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the Help! I can also do that for my Shape!

Comment: But you shouldn't. Seriously, take a look at DataTemplates and ControlTemplates.

Comment: Hey Clemens,
Yes thx I will ofc have a look and maybe change that because that Usercontrols stuff things in making me crazy sometimes.